# Write more lines TMemo (Delphi XE)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, tmemo

In a `TMemo`, I must report information on multiple lines:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ids: TidIpWatch;
  Speed: Double;
begin
 ids := TidIpWatch.Create;
 Speed := GetCPUSpeed;
 Memo1.Text := 'IP:' + (ids.LocalIP) + (Tipo_cpu);
 Memo1.Text := 'CPU: ' + (Tipo_cpu) + ' ' + Format('%f', [Speed]);
 ids.Free;
 end;
```

But I don't know how to implement the TMemo function to write on multiple lines.

Comment: Nitpick: `TMemo` is a class, not a function.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`TMemo.Lines.Add`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Add) to append a new line.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ids: TidIpWatch;
  Speed: Double;
begin
  ids := TidIpWatch.Create;
  try
    Speed := GetCPUSpeed;
    Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate();
    try
      Memo1.Lines.Add('IP:' + (ids.LocalIP) + (Tipo_cpu));
      Memo1.Lines.Add('CPU: ' + (Tipo_cpu) + ' ' + Format('%f', [Speed]));
    finally
      Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate();
    end;
  finally
    ids.Free;
  end
 end;
```

Also remember to use try-finally blocks to avoid memory leaks

Comment: (+1) Not only memory leaks, but all kinds of resource leaks. In this very example, you protect one object ("memory" + potentially other stuff) and the line lock.